# Option menu that increases and decreases with number of arraylist objects

Tags: java, arraylist, switch-statement, optionmenu

I've created a for loop that lists all objects in my array-list but i need it to be a dynamic option menu that always ends with exit. I have used switch case option menu in other parts of the program in different methods. But I'm not sure how to create an incrementing case switch in here or if it would have to be put into the for loop?

```
private static void subCar(Scanner keyboard, CarLot carLot) {

  if (carLot.getCar().size() == 0) {
      System.out.println("No Cars on the Car Lot to Remove");
  }else {
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("Cars Available to Remove: ");
      System.out.printf("%-7s%-6s%-35s%-5s\n","Option"," ID","Make/Model/Year","Price");

      for (int index=0; index < carLot.getCar().size(); index++) {
           System.out.printf("%-7s%-6s%-2s%-5s\n",carLot.getCar().get(index).getID(),
                carLot.getCar().get(index).getMake(),carLot.getCar().get(index).getModel(),
                carLot.getCar().get(index).getPrice());
       }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to create a menu option so I can select which object to delete from my array-list
I want the output to look like this:

```
option   ID    Make/Model/Year          Price
1.       2     Chevrolet cavalier 2000  1999.99
2.       Exit
enter option:
```

exit option needs to always come last

Comment: put `carLot.getCar().get(index)` in a variable, and then access to its properties, don't access the list all time

Comment: have you thought about using a stack or queue made from your arraylist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last option will always be bigger then size of list of cars.

```
int option = //read it form scanner; 
if (option > carLot.getCar().size()) { 
    // exit 
} else { 
    carLot.getCar().remove(option);
}
```

To print all options and an exit one. You need to extract index outside the loop, loop and one print after loop. One of the example:

```
int index = 0;
for (; index < carLot.getCar().size(); index++) {
    System.out.printf("%-7s%-6s%-2s%-5s\n",
        index,
        carLot.getCar().get(index).getID(),
        carLot.getCar().get(index).getMake() + " " + carLot.getCar().get(index).getModel(),
        carLot.getCar().get(index).getPrice());
}
System.out.printf("%-7s%-6s", index, "Exit");
```